# Customising title header of ModernCV template

Tags: moderncv

So I want to customise CV using the ModernCV template. I am using the classic style but want to have the Personal information written in the CV title and under the First and Last name.

Unfortunately I have a problem with getting everything to go where i want it to. Hopefully this picture better explains what I have (top) and what I want to get (bottom).

[image: Top the results from the code and bottom the sought results]

Here is the code I am using:

```
\newlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}
\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{0pt}% dummy value
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
% recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
\recomputecvlengths%
% optional detailed information (pre-rendering)
\def\phonesdetails{}%
\collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
\protected@edef\phonesdetails{\phonesdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
\def\socialsdetails{}%
\collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
\protected@edef\socialsdetails{\socialsdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
\newbox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}%
\savebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}{%
\addressfont\color{color2}%
\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}%
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet% 
\ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
  \phonesdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
  \socialsdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
\end{tabular}}%
% optional photo (pre-rendering)
\newbox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
\savebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}{%
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
 {
    \@initializelength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}% Damit Länge bekannt bei Name
    \settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{0pt}%
  }%
  {%
   \setlength\fboxrule{\@photoframewidth}%
   \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
     \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
   {\color{color1}\framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}}
    \@initializelength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}% 
    \settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}%
  \llap{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of 
  }%
% end define optional picture
% optional detailed information (rendering)
% name
%    \parbox[b]{\textwidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{%
{   \raggedright\namefont{\color{color2!50}\@firstname} {\color{color2}\@familyname}}\par
\hfill\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
%    \parbox[b]{\textwidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{%
%   \raggedleft\namefont{\color{color2!50}\@firstname} {\color{color2}\@lastname}}%\familyname
\\[-.35em]%
{\color{color2!50}\rule{\textwidth}{.25ex}}%
% optional title
% {   \raggedright\namefont{\color{color2!50}\@firstname} {\color{color2}\@familyname}}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\null\hfill\titlestyle{\@title}}\\[2.5em]% 
% optional quote
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
{}%
{{\null\hfill\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\hfill\null\\[2.5em]}}%
\par}%
```

I am very new at this so I am not sure if I have included all important code, unless please let me know what I should also include.

Many thanks for the help!

/Tobias

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another option. I have slightly modified your code, so substitute yours with this one:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
% recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
\recomputecvlengths%
% optional detailed information (pre-rendering)
\def\phonesdetails{}%
\collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
\protected@edef\phonesdetails{\phonesdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
\def\socialsdetails{}%
\collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
\protected@edef\socialsdetails{\socialsdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
\newbox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}%
\savebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}{%
\addressfont\color{color2}%
\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}%
\makenewline
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
  \phonesdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
  \socialsdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
\end{tabular}}%
% optional photo (pre-rendering)
\newbox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
\savebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}{%
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
 {
    \@initializelength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}% Damit Länge bekannt bei Name
    \settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{0pt}%
  }%
  {%
   \setlength\fboxrule{\@photoframewidth}%
   \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
     \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
   {\color{color1}\framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}}
    \@initializelength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}%
    \settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}%
  }%
% end define optional picture
% optional detailed information (rendering)
% name
%    \parbox[b]{\textwidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{%
{\raggedright\namefont{\color{color2!50}\@firstname} {\color{color2}\@familyname}}\\[1em]
\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of
\hfill\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
%    \parbox[b]{\textwidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{%
%   \raggedleft\namefont{\color{color2!50}\@firstname} {\color{color2}\@lastname}}%\familyname
\\[-.35em]%
{\color{color2!50}\rule{\textwidth}{.25ex}}%
% optional title
% {   \raggedright\namefont{\color{color2!50}\@firstname} {\color{color2}\@familyname}}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\null\hfill\titlestyle{\@title}}\\[2.5em]%
% optional quote
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
{}%
{{\null\hfill\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\hfill\null\\[2.5em]}}%
\par}%
\makeatother
```

This is the result

[image]

inserting that code in a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic}                             % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue}                               % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}         % to set the default font; use '\sfdefault' for the default sans serif font, '\rmdefault' for the default roman one, or any tex font name
%\nopagenumbers{}                                  % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page

% character encoding
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       % if you are not using xelatex ou lualatex, replace by the encoding you are using
%\usepackage{CJKutf8}                              % if you need to use CJK to typeset your resume in Chinese, Japanese or Korean

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}                % if you want to change the width of the column with the dates
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm}           % for the 'classic' style, if you want to force the width allocated to your name and avoid line breaks. be careful though, the length is normally calculated to avoid any overlap with your personal info; use this at your own typographical risks...

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}% optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the "postcode city" and "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}                   % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the optional "type" of the phone can be "mobile" (default), "fixed" or "fax"
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}                         % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}                        % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[twitter]{jdoe}                             % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[github]{jdoe}                              % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\extrainfo{additional information}                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}                       % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; '64pt' is the height the picture must be resized to, 0.4pt is the thickness of the frame around it (put it to 0pt for no frame) and 'picture' is the name of the picture file
\quote{Some quote}                                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted

% to show numerical labels in the bibliography (default is to show no labels); only useful if you make citations in your resume
%\makeatletter
%\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
%\makeatother
%\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{[\arabic{enumiv}]}% CONSIDER REPLACING THE ABOVE BY THIS

% bibliography with mutiple entries
%\usepackage{multibib}
%\newcites{book,misc}{{Books},{Others}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
% recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
\recomputecvlengths%
% optional detailed information (pre-rendering)
\def\phonesdetails{}%
\collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
\protected@edef\phonesdetails{\phonesdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
\def\socialsdetails{}%
\collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
\protected@edef\socialsdetails{\socialsdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
\newbox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}%
\savebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}{%
\addressfont\color{color2}%
\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}%
\makenewline
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
  \phonesdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
  \socialsdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
\end{tabular}}%
% optional photo (pre-rendering)
\newbox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
\savebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}{%
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
 {
    \@initializelength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}% Damit Länge bekannt bei Name
    \settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{0pt}%
  }%
  {%
   \setlength\fboxrule{\@photoframewidth}%
   \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
     \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
   {\color{color1}\framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}}
    \@initializelength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}%
    \settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}%
  }%
% end define optional picture
% optional detailed information (rendering)
% name
%    \parbox[b]{\textwidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{%
{\raggedright\namefont{\color{color2!50}\@firstname} {\color{color2}\@familyname}}\\[1em]
\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of
\hfill\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
%    \parbox[b]{\textwidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{%
%   \raggedleft\namefont{\color{color2!50}\@firstname} {\color{color2}\@lastname}}%\familyname
\\[-.35em]%
{\color{color2!50}\rule{\textwidth}{.25ex}}%
% optional title
% {   \raggedright\namefont{\color{color2!50}\@firstname} {\color{color2}\@familyname}}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\null\hfill\titlestyle{\@title}}\\[2.5em]%
% optional quote
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
{}%
{{\null\hfill\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\hfill\null\\[2.5em]}}%
\par}%
\makeatother

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}                          % to typeset your resume in Chinese using CJK
%-----       resume       ---------------------------------------------------------
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\end{document}
```

---

### EDIT (after your comments)

To have the photo top-aligned with the name, substitute the code between `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` above with this one:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
% recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
\recomputecvlengths%
% optional detailed information (pre-rendering)
\def\phonesdetails{}%
\collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
\protected@edef\phonesdetails{\phonesdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
\def\socialsdetails{}%
\collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
\protected@edef\socialsdetails{\socialsdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
\newbox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}%
\savebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}{%
\addressfont\color{color2}%
\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}%
\makenewline
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
  \phonesdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
  \socialsdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
\end{tabular}}%
% optional photo (pre-rendering)
\newbox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
\savebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}{%
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
 {}%
  {%
   \setlength\fboxrule{\@photoframewidth}%
   \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
     \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
   {\color{color1}\framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}}
%    \@initializelength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}%
%    \settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}%
  }%
% end define optional picture
% optional detailed information (rendering)
% name
  \newlength{\makecvtitledetailswidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitledetailswidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}%
  \newlength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}%
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt}}% check for dummy value (equivalent to \ifdim\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt)
    {\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{\textwidth-\makecvtitledetailswidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth}}%
    {}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\makecvtitlenamewidth}%
\vspace*{0pt}
\raggedright\namefont{\color{color2!50}\@firstname} {\color{color2}\@familyname}\\
\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of
\end{minipage}%
\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth-\makecvtitlenamewidth}
\vspace*{0pt}%
\raggedleft\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
\end{minipage}%
%   \raggedleft\namefont{\color{color2!50}\@firstname} {\color{color2}\@lastname}}%\familyname
\\[.5em]%
{\color{color2!50}\rule{\textwidth}{.25ex}}%
% optional title
% {   \raggedright\namefont{\color{color2!50}\@firstname} {\color{color2}\@familyname}}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\null\hfill\titlestyle{\@title}}\\[2.5em]%
% optional quote
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
{}%
{{\null\hfill\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\hfill\null\\[2.5em]}}%
\par}%
\makeatother
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks! I forgot to include also that I wanted the title (name) to align with the top of my picture, but the solution of @gonzalomedina did solve this as well. I haven't yet managed to find what is the difference between your solutions however.

Comment: @Tobias I've added another solution with the photo top-aligned.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one option, using a redefinition of `\makecvtitle`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  % optional detailed information (pre-rendering)
  \def\phonesdetails{}%
  \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
    \protected@edef\phonesdetails{\phonesdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
  \def\socialsdetails{}%
  \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
    \protected@edef\socialsdetails{\socialsdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
  \newbox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}{%
    \addressfont\color{color2}%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline \addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
      \phonesdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
      \socialsdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
    \end{tabular}%
  }%
  % optional photo (pre-rendering)
  \newbox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
    {}%
    {%
      \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
      \color{color1}%
      \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}%
      \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
      \framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}}%
  % name and title
  \newlength{\makecvtitledetailswidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitledetailswidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}%
  \newlength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}%
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt}}% check for dummy value (equivalent to \ifdim\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt)
    {\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{\textwidth-\makecvtitledetailswidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth}}%
    {}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\makecvtitlenamewidth}%
    \namestyle{\@firstname\ \@lastname}\par\bigskip\noindent%
    \usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}    
  \end{minipage}%
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth-\makecvtitlenamewidth}
    \raggedleft\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}
  \end{minipage}%
  \par\bigskip
  {\color{color2}\hrulefill}
  \par\medskip%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\hfill\titlestyle{\@title}\par}
  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}}%
  \par}% to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \makecvtitle
\makeatother
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}
\quote{Some quote}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, it produced exactly what I wanted. If I understand it correctly, you assign some width to the right for the photo and then produce the text for the title and information box, and lastly add the picture, line etc. ?

Comment: @Tobias Yes, that's basically what I did.

Comment: Thanks, hopefully next time I can figure out how to redesign it myself :)